# Kendo UI Mobile : Which widget to use for a form toolbar?

Tags: button, tabs, kendo-mobile

I am now evaluating Kendo Mobile with the trial version.

In the application that I want to develop, I need a toolbar in which I will have buttons like Add, Save, Remove, Copy, Cancel

I thought that the best solution that answers my form appearance expectations would be the tabstrip object in Kendo UI Mobil but afterwards I got confused if this idget should be the correct solution.

The thing is

1. Some options (= tabs in this case) should ve unavailable in some cases
2. More than 1 option will be available at the same time
3. The click needs to trigger a function, not a page change

I also thought may be I could use a buttongroup instead but also for this I am not sure..

what would you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using tabstrip is not the best solution for you to go with if all you want is to trigger is a function call and not a page change.

Tabstrip is basically used to view different contents or pages on selecting different topics.
 Grouping buttons is also not a best usage,because for add,remove etc functions you described it is best for the buttons to not be grouped and act independently because,button group the function for each button should be written and accessed using index of the button and removing a single button from DOM is difficult if the button is grouped.

I suggest you use individual buttons and align them to make it look like they are in a tab.This way you can easily write individual events for the buttons.And also incase you want to remove an individual button from the DOM it is easier,as each button is independent of the other.

I used a similar type in my application.It is to add and remove items in a list.It works

Comment: thank you @ShinyJos. In jQueryMobile you can put a navbar inside the footer which is basically a horizontal listview.. Did you use something like this?

Comment: Iam not sure of what you are asking,Iam assuming that what you are asking is can we arrange list elements horizontally.The answer to that is,yes its achievable in Kendo,and I done it..Its just all about the css properties you specify for each elements.It will do the trick